# What does `bash date` mean?

Tags: bash

```
$ bash date
/bin/date: /bin/date: cannot execute binary file

$ bash -c date
Thu Apr 14 19:27:08 EDT 2016
```

What does the error message of `bash date` mean? What does `bash` expect `date` to be?

Answer (score 3):

The reason bash throws this error is becaue `/bin/date` is a binary file. It expects it to be a shell script, and it would work if it was.

```
bash file
```

means you execute a shell script called `file`, but with `-c` it reads the input as a sequence of bash commands.